# I Try to get some data with order by date, number and get each item last price

Tags: mysql, sql, phpmyadmin

Sorry i kind of beginner in mysql. I want to order my data by date, order_number, and get each item bought price

```
id | order_number | product_name | order_date | price
 1 | A0919-002    | Bottle       | 2019-09-29 | 20000
 2 | A0919-001    | Bottle       | 2019-09-29 | 10000
 3 | A0819-004    | Bottle       | 2019-08-30 | 40000
 4 | A0819-003    | Bottle       | 2019-08-30 | 30000
```

i have tried, but can't get my expected result. and i believe using this kind of subquery is going to kill my performance.

I'm trying to use LEFT JOIN/JOIN but i can't think what i have to do.

```
SELECT id
     , order_number
     , product_name
     , order_date
     , price
     , IFNULL(
           (SELECT price 
              FROM order_d 
             WHERE order_date <= od1.order_date
               AND product_name = od1.product_name 
               AND id != od1.id 
             ORDER 
                BY order_date DESC
                 , CAST(SUBSTRING(order_number, 7, 3) AS INT) DESC 
             LIMIT 1
            ), '-') LastPrice
  FROM order_d od1
 WHERE order_date <= '2019-09-30' 
 ORDER 
    BY od1.order_date ASC
     , CAST(SUBSTRING(od1.order_number, 7, 3) AS INT) ASC
```

I expect

```
A0819-003 | Bottle | 30000 : Last Price : -
A0819-004 | Bottle | 40000 : Last Price : 30000
A0919-001 | Bottle | 10000 : Last Price : 40000
A0919-002 | Bottle | 20000 : Last Price : 10000
```

Comment: In your question. Does A0919-001 and A0819-001. Is this possible? Can you provide more data

Comment: The dates are same, how do you decide which one is earlier?

Comment: I think you need to use lead and lag functions in mysql. check this link out : https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/mysql-lead-and-lag-function/

Comment: a.order_number, 7, 3 ? A typo?

Comment: @MohinuddinLuhar thats old database design, and i can't do anything. or if i can redesign, it will waste my time again. so maybe theres some kind of trick to get my report.. :(

Comment: Last price looks more like next price..

Comment: @SalmanA i can't say it's reliable but the earliest date, number(A-mm-yy-number) and the earliest "data" created..

Comment: @P.Salmon oh yep i forgot to correct it. thanks

Comment: @P.Salmon its Last Price because i need what is my product last price before i buy "now" product. so i can see the price differences between "now" and "previous" product

Comment: Just fix your schema. You can see that it's flawed.

Answer (score 0):

I am not convinced your expected output is correct since id is more relevant than the date in determining the order in which orders happened. If you are adament that ID is not important then you are stuffed since date is not adequate (having duplicates) to determine the order of events and neither is order number

```
   SELECT id, order_number, product_name, order_date, price,
            IFNULL((SELECT price 
                        FROM t 
                        WHERE id > od1.id
                        AND product_name = od1.product_name 
                        ORDER BY id asc, 
                        CAST(SUBSTRING(order_number, 7, 3) AS INT) DESC LIMIT 1), '-') LastPrice
FROM t od1
WHERE order_date <= '2019-09-30' 
ORDER BY od1.id desc, CAST(SUBSTRING(od1.order_number, 7, 3) AS INT) ASC

+------+--------------+--------------+------------+-------+-----------+
| id   | order_number | product_name | order_date | price | LastPrice |
+------+--------------+--------------+------------+-------+-----------+
|    4 | A0819-003    | Bottle       | 2019-08-30 | 30000 | -         |
|    3 | A0819-004    | Bottle       | 2019-08-30 | 40000 | 30000     |
|    2 | A0919-001    | Bottle       | 2019-09-29 | 10000 | 40000     |
|    1 | A0919-002    | Bottle       | 2019-09-29 | 20000 | 10000     |
+------+--------------+--------------+------------+-------+-----------+
4 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Comment: Thanks. and i just found this case.. and this case possible..
insert 1 row: 5, 'A0819-004', 'Bottle', '2019-08-30', '50000' 
Thats why i can't trust the id. im just rely by it date, number and earliest data entry